# Draw shapes between coordinates

Tags: performance, graphics, draw

Given some random w and h and 4 coordinates(x1, y1)...(x4, y4) check if x, y counters are inside those 4 coordinates.

I am trying to fill the space between those 4 coordinates, they will usually form a rectangle shape, but at different rotations.

At the moment I have a nested for loop to move over my "canvas", but I am failing to find a way to check if my counters are inside the coordinates.

I have looked at line drawing algorithms to build this, but so far no luck.

Can someone point me to some resources please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a point is inside a triangle, take the orientation

```
(y2 - y1)*(x3 - x2) - (y3 - y2)*(x2 - x1)
```

the sign is zero if the points are linear, otherwise it is negative for counter-clockwise and positive for clockwise. If orientation ABC, ABD, and ACD is the same, then A is in the triangle BCD.

So we can first check our convex hull which will either be a line, a triangle, or a quad. If it is a triangle, we can easily test for further points inside. It it is a convex quad, the test also works, but we have to add an extra point.